# WSO2 - Identityt Server - ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager

Tags: ldap, wso2, claims, wso2-identity-server

I have installed WSO2 Identity Server, configure the file user-mgt.xml (as ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager) in order to connect to my OpenLdap server.

1.- If I create an "inetOrgPerson" in LDAP, I can see this user at WSO2 admin console (users and roles)
2.- If I create a user with its password (no more data at the beginning) via WSO2 admin console and I can see this user in my LDAP.

But, here it is my problem. If I go to wso2 admin console, search for a user , to the "user profile" and update it, I obtain this error
"Error while updating user profile of test2. Error is: unknown"

On the log I have this error.

```
{org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.ui.client.UserProfileCient} -  org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: unknown
```

Could anyone help me, please?

Thanks a lot in advance.
Best regards

Comment: Update your question with full sacktrace of the error

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved it.
My problem was that I had claims named in one way at WSO2 and with other name at my LDAP (you can configure this on the administration console of WSO2, Claims, List, click on "http://wso2.org/claims")
Example attached (CN in my LDAP, mapped to fullname of WSO2)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvWUR.jpg)